# Conditional replacing with str_replace

Tags: r, regex

I have this kind of data:

```
d = as.character(c("1,23", "1,23.23", "1.23", "-1.2", "1,23.234"))
```

If a string has a punctuation mark and a comma, I want to remove the characters behind the punctuation mark and the punctuation mark itself.

The result should look like this:

```
 d = as.character(c("1,23", "1,23", "1.23", "-1.2", "1,23"))
```

The problem is that I can't use str_replace because it would also remove the other strings.

```
library(stringr)

str_replace(d,"\\.[0-9]+", "")
[1] "1,23" "1,23" "1"    "-1"   "1,23"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can match the pattern of one or more digits followed by a comma or dot and one or more digits, capture as a group (`(...)`) and in the replacement, use the backreference (`\\1`) of the group

```
sub("^(-?\\d+[,.]\\d+).*", "\\1", d)
#[1] "1,23" "1,23" "1.23" "-1.2" "1,23"
```

---

Or use the same pattern in `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(d, "^(-?\\d+[,.]\\d+).*", "\\1")
#[1] "1,23" "1,23" "1.23" "-1.2" "1,23"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since our data seems to be valid, this expression might work, if lookaround would be OK to use:

```
(?<=,)(.+)(\..+)
```

here we would be only capturing those numbers that I'm guessing would be undesired.

Our code might look like:

```
str_replace(d, "(?<=,)(.+)(\..+)", "\\1")
```

or

```
sub("(?<=,)(.+)(\..+)", "\\1", d)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5oBiWp/1/)